# Lubuntu 12.04 random lock ups - next steps?

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, lockup

**Setup**

- Lubuntu 12.04, XP dual boot
- ATI RS480 graphics

**Problem**
I get random lockups about once every 3 hours or so.

**Symptoms**

- PC hangs with (typically) a small bar-code style square in top left quadrant of the screen or else a totally white screen.
- nothing entered at the keyboard causes any response (ALT SYSREQ b etc)
- power off/on is necessary to get going again
- has happened with both Firefox and Chromium, so can't blame the browser
- cannot ping or ssh to the PC from another device on the same LAN when it happens
- nothing is output on Netconsole (on the same LAN) at the moment of the lockup
- XP never locks up so it can't be bad memory

Comment: Check .xsession-errors in your home directory, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/dmesg` for errors. Try `SYSREQ S` to sync disks before power cycle.

Comment: I can't see anything in those log files that looks significant. Syslog : theres nothing around the time of the latest crash. Dmesg : assuming  the timestamp is the number of seconds since boot, then theres nothing there either.Xorg : this has no timestamp at all, but none of the messages in there look relevant.

Comment: OP hasn't signed on in ~5 years and this unanswered question is about EOL Ubuntu version. VTC as `not reproducible`.